# Is the square modulus of the cross product between three-vectors a Lorentz invariant?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

Is the square modulus of the cross product between two vectors $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ ,i.e., $(\vec{v_1}\times\vec{v_2})^2$, a Lorentz invariant or not? The result of a cross product between two vectors is again a vector but is its square modulus a Lorentz invariant or not?

Comment: have a look http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/veltran.html

Comment: It’s a Euclidean invariant.

Comment: Is there some reason that you thought it ought to be Lorentz-invariant? It doesn’t involve time in any way. Lorentz boosts “mix” space and time.